# Remove blank line between h1 and paragraph

Tags: html

I want to remove the blank line(s) between any h(n) and a paragraph using HTML only.
 I tried the following in jsfiddle and hscripts.com/tutorials/css/paddingp5.php and it appeared to work. But it's not working for my page. What am I doing wrong?
Thank you

```
<h2 span style="text-align:left; margin:0; padding:0;">Quiet the Mind</h1>  
    <p>Meditation is a "quieting" of the mind.</p>
```

Oh. OK. I see one thing that I did wrong. I forgot the ending span tag . Looking good. The code left only one blank line which is ok.

Now, can all blank lines between h(n) and a paragraph be removed using HTML only?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<h2 span style="text-align:left; margin:0; padding:0;">Quiet the Mind</h1>  
<p style="margin: 0; padding: 0">Meditation is a "quieting" of the mind.</p>
```